# Cannot Switch Headset to HSP/HFP

Tags: bluetooth

I am attempting to use a Logitech H800 Bluetooth headset in Ubuntu 16.04 64bit. It worked fine in Ubuntu 14 and 12. The output is being received, but I cannot select the headset as a source of input.

I believe the headset is "stuck" in AD2P Sink. When I attempt to change to the HSP/HFP profile in Blueman.

I get an error stating: "Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit"

Any assistance is appreciated.